# Problems with spring-loaded on a spring-boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, loaded, spring-loaded

I use spring-boot version 1.3.5.RELEASE together with springloaded 1.2.5.RELEASE.

I followed the instructions at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded to get spring-loaded up and running.
So far is works!
But actually it is pretty unusable, because I always get errors, once spring-loaded comes into play.

First I receive a lot of errors like:

`ERROR [FileSystemWatcher: files=#303 cl=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] o.springsource.loaded.ReloadableType: Unable to find regeneration methods for cglib proxies - proxies will be out of date for this type 
Spring Loaded: Cannot reload new version of com.sun.proxy.$Proxy131
 Reason: Type modifiers changed from=0x11 to=0x31`

Additionally there are quite a few exceptions, after a recompile (hotswap) such as:

- java.lang.IllegalAccessError
- java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Is there anything I have to do, to solve this? Actually I´m currently a little lost, what to do and why these errors are thrown.

Maybe someone as an idea?

Thanks

---

Here comes a stacktrace, if anyone is interested:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method company.app.service.RestCallHelper.<init>(Ljava/util/concurrent/Callable;)V from class company.app.service.RestCallHelper$$EPp3kAdE
at company.app.service.RestCallHelper$$EPp3kAdE.rest(RestCallHelper.java:49)
at company.app.service.RestCallHelper$$DPp3kAdE.rest(Unknown Source)
at company.app.service.RestCallHelper.rest(RestCallHelper.java)
at company.app.service.DetailsService$$EPp3kAtM.getGameInformation(DetailsService.java:40)
at company.app.service.DetailsService$$EPp3kAtM.getGamesConfig(DetailsService.java:58)
at company.app.service.DetailsService$$DPp3kAtM.getGamesConfig(Unknown Source)
at company.app.service.DetailsService.getGamesConfig(DetailsService.java)
at company.app.service.DetailsService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cf88e664.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
at company.app.aop.logging.LoggingAspect$$EPp3kAdE.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:41)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor162.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReloadedTypeInvoker$2.invoke(ReloadedTypeInvoker.java:133)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1461)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:620)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:609)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:59)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
at company.app.service.DetailsService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9857b378.getConfig(<generated>)
at company.app.controller.BasePageController$$EPp3kBPc.addConfigToModel(BasePageController.java:123)
at company.app.controller.BasePageController$$EPp3kBPc.postHandle(BasePageController.java:178)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReloadedTypeInvoker$2.invoke(ReloadedTypeInvoker.java:133)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1461)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.invokeModelAttributeMethods(ModelFactory.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel(ModelFactory.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:810)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at company.app.filter.CustomFilter$$EPp3kCiG.doFilterInternal(CustomFilter.java:66)
at company.app.filter.CustomFilter$$DPp3kCiG.doFilterInternal(Unknown Source)
at company.app.filter.CustomFilter.doFilterInternal(CustomFilter.java)
at company.app.filter.FilterWithExcludes$$EPp3kAdE.doFilter(FilterWithExcludes.java:35)
at company.app.filter.FilterWithExcludes$$DPp3kAdE.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at company.app.filter.FilterWithExcludes.doFilter(FilterWithExcludes.java)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at company.app.filter.tracking.TrackingFilter$$EPp3kAtM.doFilterInternal(TrackingFilter.java:35)
at company.app.filter.tracking.TrackingFilter$$DPp3kAtM.doFilterInternal(Unknown Source)
at company.app.filter.tracking.TrackingFilter.doFilterInternal(TrackingFilter.java)
at company.app.filter.FilterWithExcludes$$EPp3kAdE.doFilter(FilterWithExcludes.java:35)
at company.app.filter.FilterWithExcludes$$DPp3kAdE.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at company.app.filter.FilterWithExcludes.doFilter(FilterWithExcludes.java)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at company.app.filter.VisitedBetaFilter$$EPp3kAtM.doFilterInternal(VisitedBetaFilter.java:48)
at company.app.filter.VisitedBetaFilter$$DPp3kAtM.doFilterInternal(Unknown Source)
at company.app.filter.VisitedBetaFilter.doFilterInternal(VisitedBetaFilter.java)
at company.app.filter.FilterWithExcludes$$EPp3kAdE.doFilter(FilterWithExcludes.java:35)
at company.app.filter.FilterWithExcludes$$DPp3kAdE.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at company.app.filter.FilterWithExcludes.doFilter(FilterWithExcludes.java)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:261)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:52)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at company.app.security.AuthenticationFilter$$EPp3kAtM.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:64)
at company.app.security.AuthenticationFilter$$DPp3kAtM.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at company.app.security.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:68)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at company.app.config.metrics.RequestMetricsFilter$$EPp3kBPc.meterRequest(RequestMetricsFilter.java:98)
at company.app.config.metrics.RequestMetricsFilter$$EPp3kBPc.doFilterInternal(RequestMetricsFilter.java:86)
at company.app.config.metrics.RequestMetricsFilter$$DPp3kBPc.doFilterInternal(Unknown Source)
at company.app.config.metrics.RequestMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestMetricsFilter.java)
at company.app.filter.FilterWithExcludes$$EPp3kAdE.doFilter(FilterWithExcludes.java:35)
at company.app.filter.FilterWithExcludes$$DPp3kAdE.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at company.app.filter.FilterWithExcludes.doFilter(FilterWithExcludes.java)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at company.app.security.AuthenticationFilter$$EPp3kAtM.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:64)
at company.app.security.AuthenticationFilter$$DPp3kAtM.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at company.app.security.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Spring loaded updated to the version 1.2.6. Can you add your pom.

Comment: I do not use maven, but gradle. What would you need from the pom? I will upgrade to 1.2.6..

Comment: 1.2.6 still seems to be still in snapshot-mode. As it is a very minor release-change I am afraid this will not solve this issue, will it?

Comment: I have the same problem with 1.2.6.RELEASE: [Loader@18b4aac2] org.springsource.loaded.ReloadableType   : Unable to find regeneration methods for cglib proxies - proxies will be out of date for this type

Comment: Is there any update on this issue? I tried it with 1.2.8 release but having the same issue using Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, when using hibernate and postgresql. By removing the following line, the problem was solved:

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
```

Answer (score -1):

I have created an [open source boilerplate](https://github.com/montao/spring-boot-loaded) for spring-loaded with spring-boot. Now all you have to do is this:

```
git clone https://github.com/montao/spring-boot-loaded.git
gradle build
gradle bootRun
```

The above will start your spring-loaded app with spring-boot.

Comment: I am getting "ERROR 13469 --- [Loader@14dad5dc] org.springsource.loaded.ReloadableType   : Unable to find regeneration methods for cglib proxies - proxies will be out of date for this type"

Comment: @GauravSingh I updated the project today. It works with my Ubuntu Linux. I couldn't reproduce the error you got. You might want to try again or help me reproduce the error.